# How to transport a running wordpress in a docker container

Tags: linux, wordpress, docker, debian, containers

I have a linux debian server with a running wordpress on it and i would like to transfer this into a container.

How can I do it?

I thought about a running wordpress container and mount my running wordpress data, could this work? Or do i need a full LAMP Container?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a stack by +*docker compose** like the following:

```yaml
version: '3.5'

services:
    db:
        image: mysql:latest
        container_name: db
        ports:
          - "3306:3306"
        networks:
          internal:
            ipv4_address: 172.2.0.3
        volumes:
          - /data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        restart: always
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: <DB_ROOT_PASSWORD>
            MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
            MYSQL_USER: <DB_USER>
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: <DB_PASSWORD>

    phpmyadmin:
        depends_on:
          - db
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        ports:
          - "8001:80"
        networks:
          internal:
            ipv4_address: 172.2.0.4
        restart: always
        environment:
          - PMA_HOST=db
          - PMA_USER=<DB_USER>
          - PMA_PASSWORD=<DB_PASSWORD>
          - PMA_PORT=3306
        volumes:
          - phpmyadmin:/sessions

    wordpress:
        depends_on:
          - db
        image: wordpress:latest
        container_name: wordpress
        networks:
          internal:
            ipv4_address: 172.2.0.5
        volumes:
          - /data/wordpress:/var/www/html/
        ports:
          - "80:80"
        restart: always
        environment:
            WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
            WORDPRESS_DB_USER:  <DB_USER>
            WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: <DB_PASSWORD>
            WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress

networks:
  internal:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.2.0.0/16

volumes:
    phpmyadmin:
        name: phpmyadmin_data
```

As you can see it composed by:

1. MySQL container
2. Wordpress container
3. phpMyAdmin container (if you need to manage you container DB)

You should:

1. Create the stack by the above `yaml`.
2. Run wordpress configuration wizard.
3. Export the actual website by the [All-in-One Migration](https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/) plugin.
4. Reimport it on the docker wordpress instance by the same plugin.

Regards.